# Get json.item with variable item

Tags: jquery, json, variables

Javascript:

```
var json = {item1: {foo:bar},item2: {foo:bar)};

$('li').click(function() {
  var liID = $(this).attr('id'); // Outputs 'item1' or 'item2'
  var theFooValueIWant = json.liID.foo;
});
```

Pretty simple. I'm trying to get the value of the foo based off the ID of the <li> that gets clicked. But json.liID.foo looks for a liID in the json, which doesn't exist. How do I get it to look for json.the-value-of-liID instead of json.liID itself? Thanks!

Comment: Wow, I'm dumb! json[liID].foo! Of course!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var theFooValueIWant = json[liID].foo;`

Answer (score 2):

Use bracket notation:

```
var theFooValueIWant = json[liID].foo;
```